# C# Alternative to Nested Ordered Dictionaries?

Tags: c#, file, dictionary

I'm having issues with a program I'm developing. The basic essence of the program is to look through a file of election data and organize it via nested objects. For example, each individual Political Race is an object, and each Political Race object has a list of Candidate and County Results objects and so on.

My current issue revolves around the previously mentioned County Results object. I'm supposed to iterate through the file, and record the Candidate's name and the number of votes they got for each county. Currently I am using nested Ordered Dictionaries to achieve this, but it seems clunky and I am having an issue accessing them. Here's my code so far (listOrdicRows is the text file of the election read into an ordered list):

```
public CountyResults(List<OrderedDictionary> listOrdicRows, String raceCode)
{
    foreach (OrderedDictionary row in listOrdicRows)
    {
        bool duplicate = false;
        foreach (County indivCounty in CountyList)
        {
            if (indivCounty.countyName == row["county_name"].ToString() && raceCode == row["race_code"].ToString())
            {
                duplicate = true;
                break;                            
            }
        }
        if (!duplicate && raceCode == row["race_code"].ToString())
        {
            CountyList.Add(new County(row["county_code"].ToString(), row["county_name"].ToString(), row["precincts"].ToString(), row["precincts_reporting"].ToString()));
        }
    }
    populateCountyDict(listOrdicRows);          
}

public void populateCountyDict(List<OrderedDictionary> listOrdicRows) //Dynamically populates County Dictionary
{
    foreach (County x in CountyList)
    {
        String CountyName = x.countyName;
        List<OrderedDictionary> candidatesWithVotes = null;
        foreach (OrderedDictionary row in listOrdicRows)
        {
            if (CountyName == row["county_name"].ToString())
            {
                OrderedDictionary tempDictionary = new OrderedDictionary();
                tempDictionary.Add(row["candidate_name"], row["total_votes"]);
                candidatesWithVotes.Add(tempDictionary);
            }
        }
        countyDict.Add(CountyName, candidatesWithVotes);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I'm exceedingly stuck. Someone asked for what the file looks like, and here's a few lines

```
ElectionDate | PartyCode | PartyName  | RaceCode | OfficeDesc                   | CountyCode | CountyName | Juris1num | Juris2num | Precincts | PrecinctsReporting | CanNameLast | CanNameFirst | CanNameMiddle | CanVotes
------------ | --------- | ---------- | -------- | ---------------------------- | ---------- | ---------- | --------- | --------- | --------- | ------------------ | ----------- | ------------ | ------------- | --------
2020/08/18   | REP       | Republican | USR      | United States Representative | ESC        | Escambia   | 001       |           | 0         | 0                  | Gaetz       | Matt         |               | 29272   
2020/08/18   | REP       | Republican | USR      | United States Representative | HOL        | Holmes     | 001       |           | 6         | 6                  | Gaetz       | Matt         |               | 2131    
2020/08/18   | REP       | Republican | USR      | United States Representative | OKA        | Okaloosa   | 001       |           | 52        | 52                 | Gaetz       | Matt         |               | 25861
```

Comment: "Seeks clunky" is somewhat opinionated unless you can objectively state what you don't like about it.  And "I am having an issue accessing them" must be accompanied by a description of the issue.  Describe it with at least as much details as you would describe a bug report: in addition to providing the code (which you did) you should also describe the input, expected results, and actual results.  You should also outline steps you have tried so far to fix it, and call attention to where you think your misunderstanding of the situation is.

Comment: @Wyck My main issue with this program is that it is so interlinked that I am not really able to diagnose my issues until it is fully coded. My trouble with accessing them is I don't know how to basically at all, as my teacher is poor at describing his processes yet tests them despite it not being in the same chapter we are studying.

Comment: I hear a bit of frustration and desperation and urgency.  It's okay to ask questions here.  But you have to ask specific questions.  You haven't made it clear what parts of your code ARE working and which parts ARE NOT working.  Focus on one part, like "how can I turn the `canVotes` value into an integer?"  Or "how can group the votes by candidate and compute the sum of votes?" or whatever part you're having problems with.  And don't just respond to me.  Edit your question and improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Linq can make it a bit easy and readable.

I have created a sample file to just few columns

[image]

Next is code

```
   public class ElectionInfo
    {
        public string Race { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public int VoteCnt { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<ElectionInfo>> dict1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\x1\TextFile2.txt")
        .Select(record => record.Split(','))
        .Select(cell => new ElectionInfo() { Race = cell[0], County = cell[1], FName = cell[2], VoteCnt = int.Parse(cell[3]) })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Race)
        .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.ToList<ElectionInfo>())
        ;
```